# Two notions of square-integrability

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

It seems to me there are two notions for random variables / processes which get labeled **square-integrable**:

1. $EX^2_t<\infty \; \forall t$
2. $E \int^t_0 X_s^2 \; ds < \infty \; \forall t$

I suppose **(1)** is that $X_t$ is a square-integrable variable for all $t$ and **(2)** is square-integrable in both variables, but only "progressively" in $t$

My questions: What is the relationship between these two conditions? What purpose do they serve and in what context are they likely to be used?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

By Fubini's Theorem, (2) is equivalent to

$$\int_0^t E[X_s^2] ds < \infty$$

If $$E[X_s^2] = \infty$$ then $$\int_0^t E[X_s^2] ds = \infty \ ↯$$

Hence $$E[X_s^2] < \infty$$

Some specifics with $s$ and $t$ but I think (2) implies (1)